# AWS API Gateway - Custom Domain - Unable to complete operation due to concurrent modification

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

while Configure API mappings, Getting below error.

> Unable to complete operation due to concurrent modification. Please try again later.

[image]

Comment: I too am seeing this issue. Not able to figure out why?

Comment: have you figured it out till now

Comment: Nope. Raised a support ticket with AWS and waiting to hear back. Worked with people on AWS discord group no help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is resolved for me. Supposedly it is known issue in `ap-south-1` region of AWS. Workaround is to create the API Mapping using cli. The cli command to create API mapping is given below:

`aws apigateway create-base-path-mapping --domain-name <domainname> --rest-api-id <API ID> --stage <stage name> --base-path <basepathvalue>`

This worked for me. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but  aws team should fix such silly bugs

Comment: Agreed completely. Coz what it means is that REST API of AWS to do the changes is working but, UI to service call is broken.

Comment: Seeing this error even when using commandline `An error occurred (ConflictException) when calling the CreateBasePathMapping operation: Unable to complete operation due to concurrent modification. Please try again later.`

Comment: Which region are you trying this in? I ran into this issue while configuring using Console. This was the resolution suggested by AWS Support.

Answer (score 0):

Try to recreate custom domain to resolve the problem, worked for me. CLI command didn't work, raised same issue as UI.

Comment: CLI worked for me...might be QA not done on AWS products in corona Lockdown

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved for me. it is known issue for `ap-south-1` region of AWS.
CLI also not work if you logging with aws UI and CMD.
So as per aws its single instance. So if you trying from CLI and also not work it means log off from aws UI.

Hope its helpful for you.